# Debugging ERROR 000358: Invalid expression from SelectLayerByAttribute?

Tags: arcpy, select-by-attribute, error-000358

I'm creating a script tool and using the SelectLayerBy Attribute function (below),

```
arcpy.SelectLayerByAttribute_management("cities_lyr", "NEW_SELECTION", '"CRIME_INDX" <= 0.02')
```

However, I keep getting this error - ERROR 000358: Invalid expression.

Can anyone please offer some clarity here.

Comment: nothing wrong with your expression, but if you are working with a personnal gdb, it should be '[CRIME_INDX] <= 0.02'. I assume that your field is not a text field, of course.

Answer (score 5):

Make your expressions as triple quoted strings - nice and clean!

For File geodatabases:

```
"""CRIME_INDX <= 0.02"""
"""NAME = 'California'"""
```

For personal geodatabases (.mdb):

```
"""[CRIME_INDX] <= 0.02"""
"""[NAME] = 'California'"""
```